# Moment, get financial start date based on end date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have access to financial end date and need to compute the finanacial start date based on that.

This is the logic I have currently.

`moment('2017-03-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD').quarter()` would give me the quarter which in this case is 1.

I then subtract 3 months using

`moment('2017-03-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD').subtract(3, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD')` which results in 2016-12-31 and then I do all kinds of hacky computations to arrive at `2017-01-01`.

Is there an elegant way to compute the start date using moment API's.

So essentially, given

`2017-03-31` -> output: `2017-01-01`

`2017-12-31` -> output: `2017-10-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let date = '2017-12-31'    
moment(date).startOf('quarter').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

If it your goal to subtract 3 months from the end date and then result in a start date (which is the first of the month) maybe use:

`moment().startOf('month');`

[Moment Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = moment('2017-03-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD').subtract(2, 'months').startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/57925/

Comment: Consider posting runnable snippets here rather than elsewhere. Links rot, and users don't have to go to another site to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use as per below :

```
var date = moment('2017-03-31').subtract(2, 'month').startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
enter code here
```